# getting rowindex of selected row jquery

Tags: jquery

Am trying to get the rowindex of the selected row when a button inside cell is clicked.. here is my code. Please help me where am i gone wrong.. thank you

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script>
    $(document).on('click','.delrow',function() {   // Raising Click event for table row to mark as selected
                var cRow =  $(this).parent().parent();
                alert (cRow.rowIndex);
                $(this).parent().parent().remove(); //Deleting the Row (tr) Element
            });  
  </script>
</head>
<body>

    <table class ="table">
    <tr>
      <td> India </td> <td style="text-align: center"> <span style="color:red; text-align: center" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle delrow"> </span> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Malaysia </td> <td style="text-align: center"> <span style="color:red; text-align: center" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle delrow"> </span> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>  
    <td> Australia </td> <td style="text-align: center"> <span style="color:red; text-align: center" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle delrow"> </span> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> United States </td> <td style="text-align: center"> <span style="color:red; text-align: center" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle delrow"> </span> </td>
    </tr>   

    </table
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Better u can use id, if its dynamic changing rows, make sure that u should use changing ids.

Comment: $(document).on('click','.delrow',function() {   // Raising Click event for table row to mark as selected
                var cRow =  $(this).parents('tr');
               alert($( "tr" ).index( cRow ));
                $(this).parent().parent().remove(); //Deleting the Row (tr) Element
            });

Comment: P.S: you have a typo: `</table` should be `</table>`

Answer (score 0):

Simply go for `$row = $(this).closest("tr")` where `$(this)` is the clicked `.delrow`

than to get the `index` you can use either

```
alert( $row.index() );
alert( $row[0].rowIndex );
```

Example:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.delrow', function() {

  var $row = $(this).closest("tr"); // Get the .closest Row
  alert( $row.index() );
  $row.remove();                    // and delete it

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td> India </td>
    <td style="text-align: center"> <span style="color:red; text-align: center" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle delrow">&times;</span> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> Malaysia </td>
    <td style="text-align: center"> <span style="color:red; text-align: center" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle delrow">&times;</span> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> Australia </td>
    <td style="text-align: center"> <span style="color:red; text-align: center" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle delrow">&times;</span> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> United States </td>
    <td style="text-align: center"> <span style="color:red; text-align: center" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle delrow">&times;</span> </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Beware that tables can have `thead`, `tbody` and `tfoot` tags wrapping the rows.

`@row.index()` will get you the index within its parent, which is fine in most cases.
But if you want the row index and count all rows within the table, I would suggest using [`HTMLTableRowElement.rowIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement/rowIndex).

> The `HTMLTableRowElement.rowIndex` read-only property represents the position of a row in relation to the whole `<table>`.

Example visualizing the difference:

```js
$("table tr").each(function() {
  const $row = $(this);
  const [_, cell2, cell3] = $row.find("th, td");
  
  cell2.textContent = $row.index();
  cell3.textContent = this.rowIndex;
});
```

```css
table {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
  min-width: 250px;
}

caption {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0.2em;
  text-align: center;
}

thead,
tfoot {
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <caption>
    <code>$row.index()</code> vs <code>row.rowIndex</code>
   </caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>thead</th><th></th><th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>tbody</th><td></td><td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th></th><td></td><td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th></th><td></td><td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>tfoot</th><th></th><th></th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple answer to remove **td** is

```
jQuery('table tr td').slice(0, 3).remove();
```

You have to pass the value to **slice(start from, end)**. If you want to remove **tr**, make it `jQuery('table tr').slice(0, 3).remove()`;

Depend on your question